# Remove or edit Footer credits on child theme (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, themes, footer, credits

I am working on a child theme based on a free wordpress theme. On the original theme, at the bottom, two credit lines are shown. I want to edit or remove these lines but have not been able to. I tried at first to write on the style.css file .site-info { display:none; } , but it did't work out. I then went to the footer.php files and copied them on my child theme. The original theme has two footer.php files, one of them in a folder called inc-->structure-->footer.php  I played around with both files but nothing seemed to work. On the second footer.php file I tried to erase completely the if ( ! function_exists( 'kiyoshi_credit' ) ) function but my webpage still shows the credit line. It seems like it is still grabbing it from the original theme and not my child theme. Any ideas? I show you all the code on my theme, hopefully you can help me out.

The first footer.php file looks something like this:

```
<?php
/**
* The template for displaying the footer.
*
* Contains the closing of the #content div and all content after.
*
* @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
*
* @package kiyoshi
*/

?>

</div><!-- #content -->

<?php do_action( 'kiyoshi_footer_before' ); ?>

<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">

    <?php
    /**
     * @hooked kiyoshi_footer_branding - 10
     * @hooked kiyoshi_footer_widgets - 20
     * @hooked kiyoshi_credit - 30
     */
    do_action( 'kiyoshi_footer' ); ?>

</footer><!-- #colophon -->

<?php do_action( 'kiyoshi_footer_after' ); ?>
```

The second footer.php file, in the inc-->structure folder looks something like this:

```
<?php
/**
* Template functions used for the site footer.
*
* @package kiyoshi
*/

if ( ! function_exists( 'kiyoshi_footer_branding' ) ) {
/**
 * Display the branding in footer
 * @since  1.0.0     
 */
 function kiyoshi_footer_branding() {
    ?>
    <div class="footer-branding">
        <h3 class="site-title--footer"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h3>
        <?php if ( '' != get_bloginfo( 'description' ) ) { ?>
            <p class="site-description--footer"><?php bloginfo('description' ); ?></p>
        <?php } ?>      
    </div><!-- .footer-branding -->
    <?php
}
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'kiyoshi_footer_widgets' ) ) {
/**
 * Display widgets in footer
 * @since  1.0.0     
 */
function kiyoshi_footer_widgets() {
    ?>      
    <div class="footer-widgets">
        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'footer-1' ) ) { ?>     
        <?php   dynamic_sidebar( 'footer-1' ); ?>
      <?php } ?>
    </div><!-- .footer-widgets -->
    <?php
}
}

  if ( ! function_exists( 'kiyoshi_credit' ) ) {
 /**
 * Display the theme credit
 * @since  1.0.0     
 */
function kiyoshi_credit() {
    ?>      
    <div class="site-info">
        <?php printf( esc_html__( 'Proudly powered by %s', 'kiyoshi' ), '<a href="https://wordpress.org/">WordPress</a>' ); ?><br />
        <?php printf( esc_html__( 'Theme %1$s by %2$s', 'kiyoshi' ), 'Kiyoshi', '<a href="http://felixdorner.de" rel="designer">Felix Dorner</a>' ); ?>
    </div><!-- .site-info -->
    <?php
}
}
```

This is the Footer section on my style.css:

```
/* Footer */
.site-footer {
float: left;
display: block;
margin-right: 2.85714%;
width: 100%;
margin-right: 0;
padding: 60px 0 90px;
border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.site-info {
  display: none;
}
.site-footer:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.site-footer .footer-branding {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 2.85714%;
  width: 100%;
}
.site-footer .footer-branding:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.site-footer .footer-widgets {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 2.85714%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.site-footer .footer-widgets:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.site-footer .footer-widgets .widget {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 2.85714%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.site-footer .footer-widgets .widget:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.site-footer .footer-widgets .widget ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .site-footer .footer-branding {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 2.85714%;
    width: 31.42857%;
  }
  .site-footer .footer-branding:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .site-footer .footer-widgets {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 2.85714%;
    width: 65.71429%;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .site-footer .footer-widgets:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .site-footer .footer-widgets .widget {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 4.34783%;
    width: 47.82609%;
  }
  .site-footer .footer-widgets .widget:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .site-footer .footer-widgets .widget:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .site-footer .footer-widgets .widget:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 60em) {
.site-footer .footer-branding {
float: left;
display: block;
margin-right: 2.85714%;
width: 22.85714%;
  }
  .site-footer .footer-branding:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .site-footer .footer-widgets {
float: left;
display: block;
margin-right: 2.85714%;
width: 74.28571%;
margin-right: 0;
  }
  .site-footer .footer-widgets:last-child {
margin-right: 0;
  }
  .site-footer .footer-widgets .widget {
float: left;
display: block;
margin-right: 3.84615%;
width: 30.76923%;
  }
  .site-footer .footer-widgets .widget:last-child {
margin-right: 0;
  }
  .site-footer .footer-widgets .widget:nth-child(2n) {
margin-right: 2.85714%;
  }
  .site-footer .footer-widgets .widget:nth-child(2n+1) {
clear: none;
  }
  .site-footer .footer-widgets .widget:nth-child(3n) {
margin-right: 0;
  }
  .site-footer .footer-widgets .widget:nth-child(3n+1) {
clear: left;
  }
}
.site-footer {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 2.85714%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  opacity: .4;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code in your child functions.php file

```
remove_action( 'kiyoshi_footer', 'kiyoshi_credit', 30);
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a cache problem on chrome. One must delete caches almost every click.